# Recording line/character positions from generated FreeMarker templates

Tags: java, freemarker

Is there a way to record specific line/character positions from generated FreeMarker templates? The purpose would be to highlight specific sections of the generated output file without having to parse the generated output file.

For example, let's say I have this template:

```
function foo()
{
   ordinary_crap();
   ordinary_crap();
   do_something_special();<@mark foospecial>
   ordinary_crap();
}

function bar()
{
   ordinary_crap();
   do_something_really_special();<@mark barspecial>
   ordinary_crap();
   ordinary_crap();
}

function baz()
{
   foo();<@mark foo_call_1>
   ordinary_crap();
   bar();<@mark bar_call_1>
}
```

I want the `<@mark>` directive not to yield any generated output, but to associate mark names `foospecial`, `barspecial`, `foo_call_1` and `bar_call_1` with the line and position-within-a-line of where the `<@mark>` directives are located in the generated output. The example above I showed independent single points but it would be also useful to have begin/end pairs to mark specific ranges.

The alternatives I can see are

- parsing the output independently -- not always possible, for example what if there are several identical instances of something in the output, and I want to highlight a specific one of those?
- adding "mark hints" and removing them via my own postprocessing step. For example

  ```
   <mark name="years">Fourscore and seven</mark> years ago 
   something really brilliant happened to a really nice guy named
   <mark name="niceguyname">Fred</mark>.
  ```

  Then I could postprocess this and remove the `<mark >` tags (assuming they don't conflict with the rest of the content), recording positions as I go.

But both of these seem kind of hacky.

Answer (score 1):

From your `TemplateDirectiveModel` implementation (I assume that's how you implement `mark`, not with `#macro`), call `env.getCurrentDirectiveCallPlace()`. The returned `DirectiveCallPlace` has `getBeginColumn()` and `getBeginLine()` methods.